# How can i show picture in Picture component in Visual Basic

Tags: vb6

How can i show picture in Picture component in Visual Basic. if the picture is lying in this directory  D:\myPictures\flowers.jpg

Comment: did you ever solve this?  Did any of these answers help you?

Answer (score 1):

Use `LoadPicture` to load your image into the PictureBox.

```
Picture1.Picture = LoadPicture("D:\myPictures\flowers.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

in vb2010

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\1.jpg")
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Windows® Image Acquisition Automation Library v2.0 Tool: Image acquisition and manipulation component for VB and scripting](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a332a77a-01b8-4de6-91c2-b7ea32537e29) (XP SP1 or later, already in Vista and Win7) which can load, convert, manipulate, and save PNG, TIFF, JPG, GIF, and BMP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CommonDialog to add the picture in runtime.In a sub wtite

commondialog1.showOpen

Picture1.Picture = LoadPicture(commondialog1.FileName)